# Android Webview selection handles and menu seen through view on top - how to hide it?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have a main Webview and a bottom sheet that shows up occasionally, overlaying it. The bottom one is also a Webview, shown green.
The problem is that if there is any selection in the main view, the selection handles and menu show through the bottom one and I want them to hide behind.
[image]

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/my_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.gary.testandroid.TestActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_test">

<com.example.gary.testandroid.BrowseView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lview1"
android:elevation="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".62"/>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:elevation="24dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".38"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```